# Override AWS Auto-assign Public IP settings after instance launch

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

There is a limit to 5 public IP addresses (Elastic IPs) for each AWS Account and I have reached such limit.

Now I have many EC2 instances created without the "Auto-assign Public IP" attribute, which assign a public ip address at start.

This is good because we don't pay and consume valuable resources. On the other hand I cannot access directly via ssh, but only bridging between an instance that has a public ip address.

I would like to override the "Auto-assign Public IP" parameter set during instance launch, in order to restart the instances and allocate a public ip address when need. And, when the maintenance task is completed, reset the parameter and restart the instance again.

Is there any chance to change this behaviour or should assume is not possible?

Comment: AWS will happily raise your limit. Usually happens within hours at most. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing all this IP address shuffling, consider making all of your instances client on a VPN, each with their own private IP address assigned by you. I think Amazon has something like this in place, but the way I did it was by putting up an instance of the open source Openvpn server ( the Community Edition).  My little VPN routed traffic between my home network, office, and cloud-based Windows and Linux instances from 3 different providers. Seamlessly.

Comment: Even if this is an interesting suggestion, like others, it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Ultimately, this site is not the powers-that-be at AWS.  We COULD have just directed the OP to go ask them, but we did not.  Accordingly, any answer that gets him closer to a solution is fair game.

Answer (score 0):

You can [contact support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) to request a resource limit increase.

Comment: ...because it is not possible to change the setting in question, after instance launch.

Answer (score 0):

Ephemeral public IP addresses (drawn from a shared pool) are assigned at instance start: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses.

On the other hand, elastic IPs (EIPs, to which the said account limit applies) are owned by your account (until released) and are explicitly associated with EC2 instances. You can also move EIPs from one instance to another. No need to restart instance for that purpose. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html and the `--allow-reassociation` parameter.

Still, if you find yourself moving EIPs from one instance to another just for being able to access each instance via SSH, you are probably better off creating a bastion instance through which you would SSH onto other instances using an SSH `ProxyCommand`.